# How to query all entities those array type field contains at least one element of the given array using java API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GCP datastore entity that has an array type field that contains a list of elements, like [1,2,3]

Example:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity{

   @Id
   String id;

   List<String> data;
}
```

I need to build a query using GCP java API to select all entities that have at least one element of the given array in the field.

Example:
two entities:
1: [1,2,3]
2: [1,4,5]
I expect to select for input:
[1,2] - 1, 2;
[2] - 1

```
  EntityQuery.Builder queryBuilder =
                    Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setKind("testEntity");
  queryBuilder.setFilter(....)
```

I do not see a filter like "contains" or "is in" in the API. How can I build such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datastore mode indexes each unique array property value once per index. Thus to query if an array contains a value use an equality filter. [1]

`.setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq(property,value))`

[1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values